# tensorflow expand counts into ranges

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

We have a Tensor of unknown length N, containing some int32 values.
How can we generate another Tensor that will contain N ranges concatenated together, each one between 0 and the int32 value from the original tensor ?

For example, if we have `[4, 4, 5, 3, 1]`, the output Tensor should look like `[0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 0]`.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can make this work with a tensor as input by using a `tf.RaggedTensor` which can contain dimensions of non-uniform length.

```
# Or any other N length tensor
tf_counts = tf.convert_to_tensor([4, 4, 5, 3, 1])
tf.print(tf_counts) 
# [4 4 5 3 1]

# Create a ragged tensor, each row is a sequence of length tf_counts[i]
tf_ragged = tf.ragged.range(tf_counts)
tf.print(tf_ragged)
# <tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [0]]>

# Read values
tf.print(tf_ragged.flat_values, summarize=-1)
# [0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 0]
```

For this 2-dimensional case the ragged tensor `tf_ragged` is a “matrix“ of rows with varying length:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], 
[0, 1, 2, 3], 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2],
[0]]
```

Check [tf.ragged.range](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/range) for more options on how to create the sequences on each row: `starts` for inclusive lower limits, `limits` for exclusive upper limit, `deltas` for increment. Each may vary for each sequence.

Also mind that the `dtype` of the `tf_counts` tensor will propagate to the final values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have everything as a tensorflow object, then use [**`tf.range()`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range) along with [**`tf.concat()`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat).

```
In [88]: vals = [4, 4, 5, 3, 1]

In [89]: tf_range = [tf.range(0, limit=item, dtype=tf.int32) for item in vals]

# concat all `tf_range` objects into a single tensor
In [90]: concatenated_tensor = tf.concat(tf_range, 0)

In [91]: concatenated_tensor.eval()
Out[91]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32)
```

---

There're other approaches to do this as well. Here, I assume that you want a [constant tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) but you can construct any tensor once you have the full range list.

First, we construct the full range list using a *list comprehension*, make a flat list out of it, and then construct a tensor.

```
In [78]: from itertools import chain
In [79]: vals = [4, 4, 5, 3, 1]

In [80]: range_list = list(chain(*[range(item) for item in vals]))
In [81]: range_list
Out[81]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0]

In [82]: const_tensor = tf.constant(range_list, dtype=tf.int32)
In [83]: const_tensor.eval()
Out[83]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32)
```

---

On the other hand, we can also use [**`tf.range()`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range) but then it returns an array when you `eval`uate it. So, you'd have to construct the list from the arrays and then make a flat list out of it and finally construct the tensor as in the following example.

```
list_of_arr = [tf.range(0, limit=item, dtype=tf.int32).eval() for item in vals]
range_list = list(chain(*[arr.tolist() for arr in list_of_arr]))

# output
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0]

const_tensor = tf.constant(range_list, dtype=tf.int32)
const_tensor.eval()

#output tensor as numpy array
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32)
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately, this is not quite what I need. The input should be a tensorflow Tensor object, not a Python list. Hence, the output Tensor should be computed based on the input Tensor, not initialised as a constant with the desired content.

Comment: It is the same thing, since you are using a Python list for your example. The `vals` should be a Tensor object, which is not iterable. Needs to be implemented with tensorflow ops.